# Проблема с выводом python

Tags: python

Только начинаю изучать язык и хочу разобраться с функциями,поэтому зделал функцию сначала.Но у меня почему то не выводится текст

Ввёл слово cAPSlOCK

```
def error(x):

    x=x.title()
    return x
word=input()
a=word
letterupper=[]

for letter in word:
    if letter.isupper():
        letterupper.append(letter)
if len(word)-len(letterupper)==0:
    print(word.lower())
elif word[0].islower():
    if len(word)-len(letterupper)==1:
        print(error(word))
else:
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта программа проходит по пути, при котором не выполняется ни один `print`.

Условие `len(word)-len(letterupper)==0` не срабатывает, т.к. в слове две маленьких буквы.

Условие `word[0].islower()` срабатывает.

Условие `len(word)-len(letterupper)==1`не срабатывает, т.к. опять же в слове две маленьких буквы.

В результате программа заканчивает выполнение так ни разу не вызвав `print`.

Подобные проблемы удобно анализировать в отладчике пошагово проходя программу и при этом просматривая значения переменных и выражений на каждом шаге. Либо используйте отладчик из IDE, или встроенный в питон [pdb](https://habr.com/ru/post/104086/).

Comment: Но в конце ведь есть код                                                                                                                          else:
    print(word)

Comment: @ryan123rudder этот принт стоит в `else`, который относится к условиям `len(word)-len(letterupper)==0` и `word[0].islower()`, и сработает только если оба условия будут ложными, но условие `word[0].islower()` истинно и поэтому этот принт не должен срабатывать

Comment: Спасибо,теперь всё понятно